# Implement a shorten url feature in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to implement a shortened url feature in my web application.So I am using google shorten url api in angularjs using ajax but I am not getting anything in response.`

```
$http.post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=#key','http://uihacker.blogspot.ca/2013/04/javascript-use-googl-link-shortener.html').success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                $scope.shortUrl=data.id;
            }).
            error(function(data,status,headers,config){

            });
```

`

Comment: What is the status of the request (Console -> Network Tab)

Comment: Nothing is there but It goes inside an error block

Comment: Well, what's the error! `console.log(data)` and everything else inside the block

Comment: GET http://localhost:9000/post       [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1614ms]
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/first.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 47ms]
GET 
http://localhost:9000/assets/file.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 17ms]
GET 
http://localhost:9000/assets/t.jpg [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 244ms]
GET 
http://localhost:9000/assets/f.gif [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 242ms]
GET 
http://localhost:9000/a%22%22 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 10ms]
POST 
http://localhost:9000/getUrl [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 231ms]
POST 
https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url [HTTP/2.0 400 Bad Request 121ms]

Comment: GET 
http://localhost:9000/a%22http://www.socialorra.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/FBbanner_Mike-version-e1415303805168.png%22 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]

Comment: Basically it gives me a bad request error

Comment: According to the documentation you need to send `{"longUrl": "http://www.url.com/"}` as data, and remember to set correct content-type. The API do not support form-encoded data.

Comment: ^^ That's correct, but you don't need to manually set the content-type. By default angular uses 'application/json' for json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is not formed correctly based on google's docs. Try this:

```
$http.post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=#key',{longUrl:'http://uihacker.blogspot.ca/2013/04/javascript-use-googl-link-shortener.html'}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            $scope.shortUrl=data.id;
        }).
        error(function(data,status,headers,config){

        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you've got a valid key? And also that you're not actually inserting # into the start of your key?

Comment: By the way, if you're using chrome there are more developer tools than just the console. In the "Network" tab, click on the failed call to get more detailed information about it. For example, if your key is invalid then the response would say something like: `"errors": {"domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request"}`